# Essential Matrix: Pure Rotation

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

I am trying to estimate an Essential Matrix from point correspondences. I set my init values to [rx,ry,rz,tx,ty,tz] to 0.
But the first problem I encounter is, the Essential Matrix will be zero if all translation vector entries are zero.
Am I right that Essential Matrix can not be used if I got pure rotation?

Math:

```
E = R [R^T t]x
```

Hartley,Zisserman: Multiple View Geometry p.257

Should I use a linear Algorithm like 'normalized 8-point' for calculating init values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a pure rotation images are related by a homography.

Comment: I agree with that, does the translation vector refer on the camera centre?

Comment: Yes, in your expression above t is the vector from one camera center to the other's.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to estimate the essential matrix from a pure rotation (no motion) then here is what should happen.  Suppose that x'_i = R x_i.  We are looking for an essential matrix E = [t]x R' (possibly not the same as R, so I write it as R').  However, if t is anything at all
and R' = R, then you find that x_i'^t [t]x R x_i =  x_i'^t [t]x x_i', which
will always be 0, because [t]x is skew-symmetric.  Since this holds for any t,
it follows that you cannot compute translation t from purely rotational motion.
You should get the right value of R, however.